# Can not get uniform speed when camera move along the curve

Tags: three.js

I want to make camera move along the curve,it works, but when pass the turning corner,camera speed changed,looks like slowly.

```
curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(vectors);
curve.type = 'catmullrom';
curve.tension = 0.2;
this.MKY.Camera.current = this.roamCamera;
cameraWrap.add(this.roamCamera);
this.MKY.scene.add(cameraWrap);
this.MKY.update.push(roam);

function roam() {
    if(!isAutoRoam){return}
    if(progress>1 || progress==1){
        progress = 0;
        return
    }
    progress += 0.0005;
    var position = curve.getPointAt(progress);
    position.y += 1.5;
    var tangent = curve.getTangentAt(progress);
    cameraWrap.position.copy(position);
    cameraWrap.lookAt(position.sub(tangent));
};
```

`getPointAt` returns a vector for point at a relative position in curve according to arc length. I think if `progress` not change ,i will get the average speed,but it is not. I do not understend.

Comment: The segments of a Catmull-Rom spline are not of equal length, so the speed of your camera will vary. If you want to move at contant speed, you'll have to adjust your *progress* variable with the local derivative of the section where you are currently at. BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft nicely explains the approach here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14985/determine-arc-length-of-a-catmull-rom-spline-to-move-at-a-constant-speed

Comment: so `getPointAt` will not help.I misunderstand of this function.I will not get the same length arc .Thanks .

Comment: How to solve the problem in three.js?@Paul-Jan

Comment: @chen Have you tried `.getPoint()` instead of `.getPointAt()`?

Comment: yes,it does not work.

Comment: @chen Use `getPointAt( progress, position )` and try `curve.needsUpdate = true; // to force update of cached arc lengths`. Only set update when necessary.

Comment: @chen Or call, `curve.updateArcLengths();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

There is the approach, using `.getUtoTmapping()` method of `THREE.Curve()` (in the example, it's `THREE.CatmullRomCurve3`).

The [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/extras/core/Curve) says:

*.getUtoTmapping ( u, distance )*

*Given u in the range ( 0 .. 1 ), returns t also in the range ( 0 .. 1 ). u and t can then be used to give you points which are equidistant from the ends of the curve, using .getPoint.*

So, when you provide the second parameter in this method, then, if I got it correctly from the source code, it ignores the first parameter, thus you can find the point on your curve by the distance on it.

In the given picture:

- small yellow points - points, taken with `.getPoints()` method;
- big maroon points - points, whose distance between each other along the curve is 1 unit;

The code for the maroon points:

```
var unitPoints = [];
for (let i = 0; i < spline.getLength(); i++){
  let p = spline.getUtoTmapping(0, i);
  let p1 = spline.getPoint(p);
  unitPoints.push(p1);
}
var unitPointsGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
unitPointsGeometry.vertices = unitPoints;
var units = new THREE.Points(unitPointsGeometry, new THREE.PointsMaterial({size: .125, color: "maroon"}));
scene.add(units);
```

Look at the source code of the code snippet and pay attention to the `getProgress()` function.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, .1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 1.5, 3);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x181818);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(4, 8));

var spline = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(
  [
    new THREE.Vector3(-2, 0, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(-1.9, .1, .1),
    new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1),
    new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, -2),
    new THREE.Vector3(2, 0, 1)
  ]
);
spline.closed = true;
var splinePoints = spline.getPoints(200);
var lineGeom = new THREE.Geometry();
lineGeom.vertices = splinePoints;
var line = new THREE.Line(lineGeom, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  color: "orange"
}));
scene.add(line);

var sPoints = new THREE.Points(lineGeom, new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  size: .0312,
  color: "yellow"
}));
scene.add(sPoints);

var unitPoints = [];
for (let i = 0; i < spline.getLength(); i++) {
  let p = spline.getUtoTmapping(0, i);
  let p1 = spline.getPoint(p);
  unitPoints.push(p1);
}
var unitPointsGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
unitPointsGeometry.vertices = unitPoints;
var units = new THREE.Points(unitPointsGeometry, new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  size: .125,
  color: "maroon"
}));
scene.add(units);

var marker = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.125, 4, 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "red",
  wireframe: true
}));
marker.geometry.translate(0, 0, 0.0625);
marker.geometry.vertices[2].z = 0.25;
marker.geometry.vertices[4].z = 0;
scene.add(marker);

var markerLineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
markerLineGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector3());
var line = new THREE.Line(markerLineGeometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  color: "white"
}));
scene.add(line);

var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var progress = 0;

var totalLength = spline.getLength();
var speed = .66; // unit a second
var ratio = speed / totalLength;
var shift = 0;
var basePoint = 0;
var lookAtPoint = 0;

var oldPosition = spline.getPoint(0);
var speedVector = new THREE.Vector3();

function setProgress(delta) {
  if (progress > totalLength) progress = 0;
  shift = progress + speed * 2;
  shift = shift > totalLength ? shift - totalLength : shift;

  basePoint = spline.getUtoTmapping(0, progress);

  lookAtPoint = spline.getUtoTmapping(0, shift);

  line.geometry.vertices[0].copy(spline.getPoint(basePoint));
  line.geometry.vertices[1].copy(spline.getPoint(lookAtPoint));
  line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

  marker.position.copy(line.geometry.vertices[0]);
  marker.lookAt(line.geometry.vertices[1]);

  progress += speed * delta;
}

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  setProgress(clock.getDelta());
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: `getPointAt( u, result )` is supposed to work. See my comment above.

Comment: @WestLangley  Just for my understanding and clarification. Is it an overloaded method which takes two parameters? Because I found just `.getPointAt(u)` in the documentation and in the sourse code of `THREE.Curve()` it has only [one parameter too](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/fdefb19bdd8dbb7d549fa701b1324bfcd9ff1933/src/extras/core/Curve.js#L61). Or should I look at somewhere else?

Comment: Oh yeah, that was added in r88dev.

Comment: @WestLangley I get used to use the revision from `https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js`, which is not `dev` obviously) Anyway, this is useful information for the future ) Thanks!

Comment: @prisoner849 I use the same way like you, In most cases works well， but still can not get equidistant at some turning corner.I use more point give to `THREE.CatmullRomCurve3()`

Comment: @prisoner849 @WestLangley  I increase `arcLengthDivisions`, it looks better now.